# How to compute the digest for the Signing Certificate of a XAdES signature?

Tags: python, hash, certificate, xml-signature

I have the following X509 certificate:

```
MIIIHTCCBwWgAwIBAgIIF947UueTr/4wDQYJKoZIhvcNAQELBQAwgcExCzAJBgNV BAYTAlBUMTMwMQYDVQQKDCpJbnN0aXR1dG8gZG9zIFJlZ2lzdG9zIGUgZG8gTm90 YXJpYWRvIEkuUC4xHDAaBgNVBAsME0NhcnTDo28gZGUgQ2lkYWTDo28xFDASBgNV
      BAsMC3N1YkVDRXN0YWRvMUkwRwYDVQQDDEBFQyBkZSBBc3NpbmF0dXJhIERpZ2l0 YWwgUXVhbGlmaWNhZGEgZG8gQ2FydMOjbyBkZSBDaWRhZMOjbyAwMDE0MB4XDTE4 MDcwOTExNDc1OVoXDTIzMDcwOTIxNTkwMFowggEEMQswCQYDVQQGEwJQVDEcMBoG
      A1UECgwTQ2FydMOjbyBkZSBDaWRhZMOjbzErMCkGA1UECwwiQXNzaW5hdHVyYSBR dWFsaWZpY2FkYSBkbyBDaWRhZMOjbzEcMBoGA1UECwwTQ2lkYWTDo28gUG9ydHVn dcOqczEuMCwGA1UEBAwlRklMSVBFIENBUlZBTEhBSVMgRE9TIFNBTlRPUyBERSBN
      QVRPUzEPMA0GA1UEKgwGTUlHVUVMMRQwEgYDVQQFEwtCSTE1MTYxMTUxMzE1MDMG A1UEAwwsTUlHVUVMIEZJTElQRSBDQVJWQUxIQUlTIERPUyBTQU5UT1MgREUgTUFU T1MwggEiMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4IBDwAwggEKAoIBAQDBT/YzBGxbpKoufSiJ
      q6YSZ8w8HQurfMTLNz/eFf7F2lAVHhhZZLAnbXHAq4jsKcfc29J1Milq1vImHS/Z W0mxeyFu+FM0PI4VRdrjX/XqewX6e7dGIgBfkCT3EbtozS+m5ABwo6EZE0ZddPty 6Frzv65EI9DkhlKqy0qSUkOLe13su9PhoTLcFaB0dtgYkFgpIXLG6uc4Nxx2Sd44
      DilgHlyYb8nO3o1PzwkCS3DiaV1BJ8vxHusrNHMJq5uhNqkGzLLk1x3/QjgPSlF5 LvkarcU3jZEgS4YeZ9iEtlQXia1N46TU0SopM2Y26ekHJ3gfhBrr2azXMFlKmlM9 60VzAgMBAAGjggPRMIIDzTAMBgNVHRMBAf8EAjAAMB8GA1UdIwQYMBaAFEsL/oKF
      NBfyc48f91De1Vgu6h+6MEsGCCsGAQUFBwEBBD8wPTA7BggrBgEFBQcwAYYvaHR0 cDovL29jc3AuYXNjLmNhcnRhb2RlY2lkYWRhby5wdC9wdWJsaWNvL29jc3AwbwYD VR0uBGgwZjBkoGKgYIZeaHR0cDovL3BraS5jYXJ0YW9kZWNpZGFkYW8ucHQvcHVi
      bGljby9scmMvY2Nfc3ViLWVjX2NpZGFkYW9fYXNzaW5hdHVyYV9jcmwwMDE0X2Rl bHRhX3AwMDAxLmNybDCCAUkGA1UdIASCAUAwggE8MDYGCGCEbAEBAQIKMCowKAYI KwYBBQUHAgEWHGh0dHA6Ly93d3cuc2NlZS5nb3YucHQvcGNlcnQwCQYHBACL7EAB
      AjB1BgxghGwBAQECBAEAAQEwZTBjBggrBgEFBQcCARZXaHR0cDovL3BraS5jYXJ0 YW9kZWNpZGFkYW8ucHQvcHVibGljby9wb2xpdGljYXMvcGMvY2Nfc3ViLWVjX2Np ZGFkYW9fYXNzaW5hdHVyYV9wYy5odG1sMAgGBgQAj3oBAjB2BgtghGwBAQECBAEA
      BzBnMGUGCCsGAQUFBwIBFllodHRwOi8vcGtpLmNhcnRhb2RlY2lkYWRhby5wdC9w dWJsaWNvL3BvbGl0aWNhcy9kcGMvY2Nfc3ViLWVjX2NpZGFkYW9fYXNzaW5hdHVy YV9kcGMuaHRtbDAoBgNVHQkEITAfMB0GCCsGAQUFBwkBMREYDzE5OTYwOTA2MTIw
      MDAwWjCBzAYIKwYBBQUHAQMEgb8wgbwwCAYGBACORgEBMAgGBgQAjkYBBDBaBgcE AI5GAQYBDE9DZXJ0aWZpY2F0ZSBmb3IgZWxlY3Ryb25pYyBzaWduYXR1cmVzIGFz IGRlZmluZWQgaW4gUmVndWxhdGlvbiAoRVUpIE5vIDkxMC8yMDE0MEoGBgQAjkYB
      BTBAMD4WOGh0dHA6Ly9wa2kuY2FydGFvZGVjaWRhZGFvLnB0L3B1YmxpY28vcG9s aXRpY2FzL2Nwcy5odG1sEwJQVDBpBgNVHR8EYjBgMF6gXKBahlhodHRwOi8vcGtp LmNhcnRhb2RlY2lkYWRhby5wdC9wdWJsaWNvL2xyYy9jY19zdWItZWNfY2lkYWRh
      b19hc3NpbmF0dXJhX2NybDAwMTRfcDAwMDEuY3JsMB0GA1UdDgQWBBQqKpc5DNgY d1GW3eqB4W1D0TCl6jAOBgNVHQ8BAf8EBAMCBkAwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQELBQADggEB ADN1vTH/jAbMrSmXyvd8EtpdMglJYcWf+n1qhZxM4+p+x31vWY75ZhAgSsqH9bK8
      Ll6oE05X3wFMVZKBRI8BkBPWleyvbgK7q9bXGcgS9lmfmlPMuWdfFDmXAd9WOEzb Hu5Tr3rqhlt8sN5vgOl1jzZg7jnPfU/9RQtNqKJm6E/Vwbi5r9KVVFQijULzt92J dTGHzrD3WoCoZfKfZzMsevJW2sSHQAWkJiogckUu5nTv3eARvU8Sfoy5GlNYeYYe
      IbbODsWiD1M5FRqJEsThKEeVgH+ejDQMls897+fYNE/ZAmIiGzjJM4WPR7huGkjH sBBolgg/Rz0cyMmHeejEHzs=
```

and I know that the digest is

```
2ZXt/8T161gL9mW1UlORjjXBvp/v1gaHausPzeQJiWw=
```

but I cannot find the way to compute the digest.

**Edit**

I simply not know which data to apply the hash.

The objective is to put the digest on a XAdES signature and do it with python.

Answer (score 0):

The digest is simply a hash over some data. In your case I would guess its a [SHA2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-2) based on the length of 32 bytes.

The process foresees that content to be signed is hashed into a so called (message) digest and then a signature for the digest is created with the certificate (in your case RSA).

To answer your question (but I cannot find the way to compute the digest.): Use SHA2 over the content data.

If you provide some more details - e.g. which programming language you would like to use we can for sure give you more help.

**EDIT**

> I simply not know which data to apply the hash.

Do you want to **create** a signature or **validate** one? 
It sounds to like you want to validate a signature. So you have a certificate, some data and a signature - or both together? Where do you have the digest from? If you tell us more we can assist you further...

Answer (score 0):

Use the X509 certificate data to compute the digest, but you have to decode base64 format from the X509 certificate before hashing.

the example code (php) :-

```php
$X509Cert = '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';

$X509CertDecoded = base64_decode($X509Cert);  // <--- decode X509Cert from base64 format before hash
$digest = base64_encode(hash('sha256', $X509CertDecoded, true));
echo $digest;
```

and then the output will be

```
2ZXt/8T161gL9mW1UlORjjXBvp/v1gaHausPzeQJiWw=
```

Comment: I'm not sure this is a helpful answer!

Comment: Please add a specific code example on how to do that, and explain why this is the way to go?

Comment: I have add the example php code above, I think it is the same concept in python.